# Solving equations involving ceilings

Tags: python, sympy, equation, ceil

I would like to solve the equations of the following type in Python. Please let me know if there are any relevant libraries or methods to solve it. ceil(x) denotes the ceiling function.

> ceil(x/7)+3*ceil(x/12) = x

This is just a random example, not sure if there is a solution to this.

I tried looking into Sympy library of Python but I can't find a way to use it for my case.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I just voted to close this as off-topic, but you should google `numpy`

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
from sympy import ceiling
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
x = Symbol('x')

print(solve(ceiling(x/7) + 3*ceiling(x/12) - x, x))
```

which ended up in

```
No algorithms are implemented to solve equation -x + 3*ceiling(x/12) + ceiling(x/7)
```

The only thing I can think of right now is a graphical solution.

Comment: Umm...how am I supposed to implement a graphical solution in my program? Are there any methods that can find approximate solutions to such equations?

Comment: You can plot both left and right hand side of the equation. This is not useful if you are trying to get some exact result for further usage when running the program but rather if you only want to get a solution to the equation. Like I said, this is the only thing I can think of. This doesn't have to be the best possibility.